# Python Sockets - Creating a message format

Tags: python, sockets, protocols

I have built a Python server to which various clients can connect, and I need to set a predefined series of messages from clients to the server - For example the client passes in a name to the server when it first connects.

I was wondering what the best way to approach this is? How should I build a simple protocol for their communication?

Should the messages start with a specific set of bytes to mark them out as part of this protocol, then contain some sort of message id? Any suggestions or further reading appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to decide whether you want your protocol to be human readable (much more overhead) or binary. If the first, you probably want to use regular expressions to decode the messages. For this, use the python module `re`. If the latter, the module `struct` is your friend.

Second, if you are building a protocol that is somehow stateful (e.g. first we do a handshake, then we transfer data, then we check checksums and say goodbye) you probably want to create a some sort of [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to track the state.

Third, if protocol design is not a familiar subject, read some simple protocol specifications, for example by [IETF](http://www.ietf.org)

If this is not a learning excercise, you might want to build up from something else, like Python [Twisted](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Twisted-Examples)

Comment: -1 Using regular expressions to decode messages is not a good idea. If you want human-readable, then stick with something like xml that is still reasonably easy to parse quickly and robustly.

Comment: Binary is fine, but I'm wondering how to create the message itself. I'm struggling to find any information about how best to construct the messages. I understand how to write a spec, but its the intricacies of building the actual message that I am struggling with. What kind of data should I be using to mark the beginning of the message for example. How should I close each message?

Comment: That's a serialisation problem. Try XML, JSON, or (if you trust your clients and they are the same architecture) pickle.

Comment: I think the 'standard' method of binary protocols is to have a fixed sized fields for "N=number of payloads"+(N*"payload type"+"payload length"+"payload")

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the requirements, you might want to consider using [JSON](http://json.org/): use "newline" terminated strings with JSON encoding. The transport protocol could be **HTTP**: with this, you could have access to all the "connection related" facilities (e.g. status codes) and have **JSON** encoded payload.

The advantages of using JSON over HTTP:

1. human readable (debugging etc.)
2. libraries available for *all* languages/platforms
3. cross-platform
4. browser debuggable (to some extent)

Of course, there are many other ways to skin this cat but the *time to working prototype* using this approach is very low. This is worth considering if your requirements (which aren't very detailed here) can be met.

Comment: This one has a spec, with JSON-RPC: http://json-rpc.org/ http://code.google.com/p/python-jpc/

Answer (score 1):

Read some protocols, and try to find one that looks like what you need. Does it need to be message-oriented or stream-oriented? Does it need request order to be preserved, does it need requests to be paired with responses? Do you need message identifiers? Retries, back-off? Is it an RPC protocol, a message queue protocol?